# CSS in placeholder on all pages, except but one: howto?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Hi we have many pages where we wan to set the CSS

```
.cms-index-noroute .col-main .std {font-weight: bold}
.cms-index-list .col-main .std {font-weight: bold}
.cms-index-view .col-main .std {font-weight: bold}
```

We would rather write this CSS like

```
.col-main .std {font-weight: bold}
```

But there is one problem, it breaks everything on the page with selector

```
.cms-index-index
```

**Question:** Is there a CSS notation to have `.col-main .std {font-weight: bold}` work on all pages *except* the page where it resides in `.cms-index-index` placeholder.

Comment: What is the markup like? Which elements have the relevant classes?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) with the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors), assuming `.cms-index-index` is the parent of `.col-main`:

```css
:not(.cms-index-index) > .col-main .std {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class='cms-index-noroute'><span class='col-main'><span class='std'>Span 1</span></span></div>
<div class='cms-index-list'><span class='col-main'><span class='std'>Span 2</span></span></div>
<div class='cms-index-view'><span class='col-main'><span class='std'>Span 3</span></span></div>
<div class='cms-index-index'><span class='col-main'><span class='std'>Span 4</span></span></div>
```

Comment: Could the NOT hold more than one selector?

Comment: @snh_nl Yes, just separate your selectors with commas.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9k6quwu/2/):

```
.col-main .std {
    font-weight: bold
}
.cms-index-index .col-main .std {
    font-weight: normal
}
```

Selectors that are more specific will always override the ones that aren't.

Comment: Thanks. However i ask because there are hundreds of CSS lines that apply to .std and many more parent selectors that are in scope. Hence I was looking for a method not to double all the code. And a resolution like "do it everywhere unless"